# Smart Pointers and Exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, smart-pointers

I have looked over the internet and this thread looking for a complete 
answer of this situation I am facing. I have read that throwing smart 
pointers to objects is not very clever. I just want to understand why 
is this happening. I will explain the situation. Let's imagine this 
simple hierarchy:

```
class Foo 
{ 
public: virtual ~Foo() {} 
}; 

typedef tr1::shared_ptr<Foo> SPFoo; 

class FooInherited: public Foo { }; 

typedef tr1::shared_ptr<FooInherited> SPFooInherited;
```

And let's check this test code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  try 
  { 
    throw FooInherited(); 
  } 
  catch(const Foo& f) 
  { 
    cout << "Foo& caught!" << endl; 
  } 
  try 
  { 
    throw SPFooInherited(new FooInherited()); 
  } 
  catch(const SPFoo& f) 
  { 
    cout << "SPFoo& caught!" << endl; 
  } 
  return 0; 
}
```

Everything compiles but in runtime the second try-catch won't be 
executed. Can someone explain me why? Specially if lines of code like 
this work perfectly fine in runtime.

```
void function(const SPFoo& f) 
{ 
} 

... 

SPFooInherited fi(new FooInherited()); 
function(fi);
```

I do understand that the problem is that SPFooInherited does not inherit from SPFoo (even though FooInherited inherits from Foo), but It deeply would like to know what is the compiler/RTE doing differently from the function call example when catching an exception not to be able to solve de situation. Is it because the catch parameter is not the same as a function call parameter? Why Foo& works and SPFoo doesn't?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards, 
Iker.

Answer (score 13):

As you said in your question, `SPFooInherited` is not a subclass of `SPFoo`. This means that `catch(SPFoo const&)` will not catch instances of `SPFooInherited`. On the other hand, `FooInherited` is inherited from `Foo`, and so `catch(Foo const&)` will catch instances of `FooInherited`.

To understand this you do not need any special understanding of the compiler or run-time-environment. It is simply a part of the language.

The reason that the call to the function works is that `tr1::shared_ptr` has a templated non-explicit constructor that allows an implicit conversion to take place at function call sites.

That is: `tr1::shared_ptr` has the following constructor:

```
//Note the lack of explicit
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r);
```

This allows a `shared_ptr` to be constructed from a different shared pointer type. The implementation of this constructor relys on the implicit conversion from `FooInherited*` to `Foo*` to actually store the pointer in the `SPFooInherited` into the `SPFoo`. If this implicit conversion does not exist then the code will not compile, and so unsafe conversions  between `shared_ptr`s to unrelated types will not occur.

The fundamental difference between the function call and the catch is that implicit conversions will occur in the initialization of function arguments, but a catch can only match a single type (`FooInherited` is-a `Foo`, so it will match).

Answer (score 3):

Because `SPFoo` is not a subclass of `SPFooInherited`. `catch` blocks will only catch things that are in their catch list, or a public child class of what's in their catch list. `FooInherited` does inhertit from `Foo`, so catching a `Foo` will also let you catch a `FooInherited`. `SPFoo` and `SPFooInherited` are completely different and unrelated classes.